# How can I link a shrared library when I cannot include the required header files for the code within?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a problem while trying to compile one application within another framework.

Status quo: I want to do deep learning inference using Intel OpenVINO's inference engine. I was able to write a .cpp and - using cmake - create an executable that does what I want it to do. However, now, I need to include the functionality in OpenFOAM, a C++ Fluid Dynamics tool. I want to pass references to two vectors I create in OpenFOAM to OpenVINO's inference engine.

Problem: To be able to call the inference engine within the runtime of OpenFOAM, I need to compile my code using "wmake". I did that several times, you just have to use the right headers and shared libraries. However, this time the procedure fails: the problem is that there is some namespace collision between the two tools. I can compile my inference engine code on it's own, doing so I create a shared library. However, to use it, I must include the inference engine header files in the OpenFOAM code. As soon as I try to compile then, it fails, due to the namespace collision. I would prefer to not change any of the code in the background. So I am looking for another solution.

Question: As mentioned, I can create the shared libary, but I cannot include the header files. However, I know that my code would work correctly. As far as I know I cannot pass referebces to arguments to an executable, which is then changing them. therefore I am looking for an alternative way to solve this issue.

Does anybody have an idea how I could do so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the exact problem namespaces were designed to avoid. Can you elaborate on the namespace clash?

Answer (score 0):

1. First general approach: use a wrapper. Add you code to the shared library you compiled. Include your code which doesn't include original problematic code. The problem with this is that you write additional code which in general is unnecessary.
2. Wrap some of code which causes collision in a namespace. It requires code modification, what may or may be not acceptable.
3. You can play with symbol renaming in already cooked binary. For C usually it's easy, but probably you can succeed for C++ as well. Look into nm/objcopy (I don't know on what OS you are but I suspect linux based on terminology)
4. Learn what the collisions are exactly probably you can just trick the code with some #define, #include order, or removing "using namespace" derictives avoiding heavy solutions above.

I'd recommend go in the order #4, #2, #1, #3

Answer (score 0):

I believe this guide about avoiding linking collisions could help you:

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/03/static-linking-c-plus-plus/

It basically lets you change the namespaces of the 2 libraries you're using through the preprocessor or a compiler flag.